# Laravel - Artisan gives wrong base url

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

My app/config/app.php has

```
'url' => 'http://dev.domain.com/something/somethingElse'
```

Then I have a function that can be called from the application and also from an artisan command. But `URL::route('myRoute')` returns different results. When called from the application it returns `http://dev.domain.com/something/somethingElse/myRoute`, but in the artisan command `http://dev.domain.com/myRoute`.

`URL::to` has same behaviour.

Note: I do not have any other app.php file defined for other environments that could overwrite the global one.

Any ideas why this happens ?
Thanks!

Comment: An alternative that works is using Config::get('app.url').

Answer (score 11):

A Laravel-generated URL consists of a number of parts:

- Scheme: `http://`, `https://`, etc.
- Host: `dev.domain.com`, `localhost`, etc.
- Base: `something/somethingElse` (the subdirectory on the web server)
- Tail: `myRoute`, (the Laravel route parameters)

These parts are then concatenated to form the URL.

Ultimately, Laravel generates the URL using the `$_SERVER` request variables.  The function `prepareBaseUrl()` in `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` is what is ultimately used to determine the **base** part of the URL.

When you make a request through your web browser, the request goes to `~/public/index.php` and the necessary `$_SERVER` variables are populated with the correct information for Laravel to populate the **base** part of the URL.

However, when you make the request using Artisan on the command line, the request goes to the `~/artisan` script.  This means that the `$_SERVER` variables are not populated in the same way and Laravel is not able to determine the **base** part of the URL; instead, it returns an empty string `''`.

From what I can find, it doesn't look like there is any appetite from the Laravel team to enable the application to function out-of-the-box in a subdirectory, e.g. [Bugfix: domain routing for subfolder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3918#issuecomment-40238519).

I ended up working around it in the way described by @medowlock for my scripts that would be called from the command line, e.g.:

`Config::get('app.url') . URL::route('route.name', ['parameter'=>'value'], false)`

This concatenates the application URL set in the `app/config/app.php` and the *relative* URL route.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this, it helped me to better understand how Laravel deals with requests. If not for this, I would probably just be blindly pasting in code wherever something happens.

Answer (score 11):

If you use Laravel 4.2, you can call the `URL::forceRootUrl` function to explicitly define what the root url of your laravel application is.

```
URL::forceRootUrl( Config::get('app.url') );
```

Calls to `URL::to` will use the URL define in your app config file after forcing the Root URL.

Unfortunately, this isn't available in Laravel 4.1 or Laravel 4.0

Comment: Where can I put this to apply it globally in my application?

Comment: I am using L5.1, by the way

Comment: Looks like the [function is still available in 5.1](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html) so it should still work in theory.

Comment: As to where you want to put, it depends in your use case. 

Originally, I needed this because I was writing a custom artisan command that needed to generate an email with a link to the website. If your need is very specific like that I would suggest putting it in the command or controller.

If you want to set it for the entire application than you could try putting in your routes.php file. There's probably a better place to put it thought.

Comment: Thanks guys. I decided to put it in my AppServiceProvider, inside the boot() method. It's working like a charm.

Comment: `forceRootUrl ` is not available in Lumen since it uses different router.