# Laravel .htaccess subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I now have a Laravel installation with the default folder structure.
In my root folder I have a .htaccess file like this one.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # RewriteEngine On
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have to install in a subfolder WordPress.

So I would like to access to my WP installation using the URL http://www.example.com/ and to Laravel with http://www.example.com/admin.

The thing I know it's that is an .htaccess trick, but, even if I tried many kind of rewrites, I'm not still able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: The problem is that WordPress even if it's installed in a subfolder of Laravel, should be accessed from root domain www.example.com/ and laravel should be accessed from www.example.com/admin
I'm not able to rewrite them correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your root `.htaccess` you should use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Route any request begining with 'admin/' to laravel
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
# Anything else goes to Wordpress
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wp/$1
```

And in your Laravel `.htaccess` add:

```
RewriteBase /admin
```

If you can't live with the trailing slash being mandatory you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^admin(/(.*))?$ public/$2 [L]
```

Comment: The HTML seems to work fine, but, all the assets give 404.

Comment: My current .htaccess is exactly like the one you posted.

Comment: I probably didn't explain well, I have the root laravel folder that has an htaccess, inside the root folder i have the laravel public folder with another htaccess.
In the first htaccess I mentioned there's a rewrite to the public folder for Laravel, as you can see from the htaccess I posted above.
Insider my root Laravel folder there's also a wordpress/ folder.
Laravel should be used as /admin url and wordpress as the main one.

Comment: @Manu At some point you need to check if the file being requested exists or not and serve that or rewrite to the front controller. You do that with your commented out `RewriteCond` lines, but you should do it in your `public/.htaccess` I think. Could you share it ? There's where laravel's `index.php` and assets reside, right ? One of the urls giving you 404 would be helpful too.

Comment: I got it, i just changed in my .env file the APP_URL property adding /admin to the end.
But when I go to http://example.com/ without the /admin path it gives me error 500 "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @Manu I replicated the wp setup and some dummy assets and php as the laravel standin and everything works fine. Could you be missing some required php module ?

Comment: I'll try to install it locally, again from scratch

Comment: @Manu check if your apache configuration has the appropiate `AllowOverride` enabled for the wordpress `Directory`

Comment: I installed everything locally, but it seems that Laravel asset function is wrong.
When I launch from php artisan tinker this code `asset('css/custom.css')` it returns me this "http://example.com:8888/admin/css/custom.css"
but when the page gets rendered  it says "http://example.com:8888/css/custom.css".

Comment: @Manu I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750604/laravel-artisan-gives-wrong-base-url) but maybe is not relevant anymore. Since you've tried reinstalling I assume you have purged your caches ?

Comment: I tried already what you linked me, it works with assets, but it destroys the POST links...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /your-subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /your-subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: The problem is not in the WordPress htaccess, but in the Laravel one.

Comment: You don't have any route in laravel with same name as WP subdirectory right? Just confirming.