# Other routes rather than default one not working with XAMPP

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-7

I have my Laravel project, not running on my localhost XAMPP if I use the address "localhost/app/public" I get the main (i.e welcome)page(welcome.blade.php)working but when I write my other route like "localhost/app/public/anyother" it show me error message,404 | Not Found.
While the default and all other routes work fine for "php artisan serve".

There are 2 Things I want to know hope you'll not mind it.

**1. How to solve this issue for XAMPP on Laravel own application server all routes are accessible fine?**

**2. Why other routes are not working in local XAMPP while they work fine with "php artisan serve"?**

What I found for run Laravel App on XAMPP is:-

Working with xampp:

Go to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add a new line like: 127.0.0.1       yoursite.local
Go to where XAMPP is installed under xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf Then add a virtual host in the bottom of the file like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

DocumentRoot "PATH_to_laravel_folder/public"  

ServerName yoursite.local  
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there any other solution without creating Virtual Host if I accept this solution for my point #1? Any other solution if I want to use XAMPP provided URL such as "localhost/app/public"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your virtual host are not good. You are forgot the `Directory` specification tag and not allowing indexing.

Try to edit `httpd-vhosts.conf` that is located in `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` like this:

```
# VirtualHost for LARAVEL.DEV

<VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
  ServerAdmin laravel.dev
  <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can find out more the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)

> `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` are used to enclose a group of directives that will apply only to the named directory, sub-directories of that directory, and the files within the respective directories.

In other words Apache web server automatic index generation is enabled with using `Options +Indexes` or `Options Indexes` directive.

> If a URL which maps to a directory is requested, and there is no `DirectoryIndex` in that directory, then `mod_autoindex` will return a formatted listing of the directory.

Comment: Thanx but I guess, I asked 2 Questions?

Comment: @AliBhutta It's funny because it solves both your questions. You are not allowed indexing and Xampp can't find other pages

Comment: Thanks, I didn't pick what does indexing means in xampp? sorry If it seems an odd question.

Comment: Hey @AliBhutta i will update answer and try to explain indexing :)

Comment: Thanks, one more thing I would like to ask that can't we use xampp for Laravel without "VirtualHost " as you told in your answer? i.e rather than using 127.0.0.1::8000 can't I use localhost/myapp/public?

Comment: @AliBhutta "VirtualHost" is a virtual (Localhost) domain name. In the example above our domain name and URL is `laravel.dev`. It is possible to expose all your sites through one domain. i.e `localhost/myapp/public?` and `localhost/myapp2test/public?`, but why would you do that? In that case, you need to change .htaccess for redirections and you have a big risk that you will forget to change on production as well and have a nightmare. If I understand well your question?

Comment: Thanks, So in short regarding my point #2 the answer is that other routes in xampp without creating "VirtualHost", a virtual (Localhost) domain name, other routes rather than default one are not working just because we have not changed .htacess, that's why, did I get right?

Comment: Basically yes.. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52707492/3740460 it will be much clearer to you.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

Try renaming the `server.php` in your Laravel project folder to `index.php` and copy the `.htaccess` file present inside public directory to your project root folder.

**Solution 2:**

Copy `.htaccess` and `index.php` from public directory to project root folder

Change the `index.php` file as addressed below:

```
 //change line 22 to       
 require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

 //change line 36 to
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Hope one of the above solution would work well in your case.